# How to create Sql Server 2008 Cross Tab Dynamic Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables:

- **Locations**: `LocationID, LocationName`
- **Defect**: `DefectID, DefectType`
- **Feedback**: `feedbackID, DefectID, LocationID`

I need cross tab report in the below format: Number below the locations column is the total number of defects for that location. Locations can be any number. it should be dynamic..

```
DefectID  DefectType  NewYork  NewJersey  Texas  Houston
1         Defect1       0         10        3       6
2         Defect2       0          0        9      10
3         Defect3       8          8        4       6
```

I have a SQL query which is hardcoded. Also, it's not displaying the `DefectID`..

```
select 
   DefectType, 
   [1] as NewYork, 
   [4] as NewJersy,  
   [5] as Texas, 
   [6] as Houston
from (select 
             Defect.DefectID, 
             Defect.DefectType, 
             Location.LocationID  
      from Feedback
      inner join Locations on (Feedback.LocationID= Location.LocationID)             
      inner join DefectType on (Feedback.DefectID= Defect.DefectID)         
     ) p
    pivot   
     ( count (DefectID) for LocationID in ( [1], [4], [5],[6] )   ) as pvt
 order by pvt.DefectType;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't dynamically build the cross tab values with SQL Server PIVOT and pure static SQL.  You have to build the SQL dynamically, either with some external scripting language building the query, or with T-SQL using [execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

```
DECLARE @locationID int, @LocationName nvarchar(50), 
  @columnList nvarchar(max), @idList nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max) ;
DECLARE location_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT locationID, LocationName FROM Locations

SET @columnList = '';
SET @idList = '';


OPEN location_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
INTO @locationID, @LocationName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @columnList = @columnList + ', [' + @locationID + '] as [' + @locationName + ']'
  SET @idList = @idList + '[' + @locationID + '],'
END
CLOSE location_cursor

SET @sql = 'select DefectType' + @columnList + ' from (select Defect.DefectID, Defect.DefectType, Location.LocationID from Feedback inner join Locations on (Feedback.LocationID= Location.LocationID)
inner join DefectType on (Feedback.DefectID= Defect.DefectID)
) p pivot
( count (DefectID) for LocationID in (' + left(@idList,len(@idList)-1) + ') ) as pvt order by pvt.DefectType'

EXECUTE (@sql)
```

I haven't tested this, obviously, but it should work (with minor tweaks possibly needed).